# Can subject–auxiliary inversion in conditionals be used with non-auxiliary (arbitrary) verbs?

Tags: conditionals, auxiliary-verbs, subject-verb-inversion

Can I say something like

> Come you there, I'll get you.

?

Or should I only say something like

> Should you come there, I'll get you.

?

I understand that it looks like I must use an auxiliary verb in a subject-auxiliary inversion kind of by definition :) But I'm just not sure if I absolutely need it.

Comment: You shouldn't use either of them - the first one is effectively "archaic", and the second is hopelessly dated / stilted / poetic. Do the same as native speakers, and ditch the subjunctive: ***If** you come there, I'll get you.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers The first isn’t archaic; it’s wrong. Twice.

Comment: But "should" is already an auxiliary verb.... Do you want to say that you will pick someone up [I'll get you] if they arrive at some location? I *think* you are asking: "Should you decide to come, I'll pick you up"

Comment: @tchrist: [***Say you so**, and I should like such a handsome gentlewoman for a bed-fellow:—What say you, Mistress?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22say+you+so+and+I%22) It might be "wrong, ungrammatical" today, but such usages certainly  did occur long ago. And although I had to go to some trouble to find a context with a heavily implied ***If*** before it, I don't see that has any real bearing on the (one-time! :) validity of the syntax - so in principle I could have cited Byron's *Think you that I have heard This fellow's tale without some feeling?*

Comment: [...Oh ! Barnum, Barnum, you're a goose, If think you that all women Have let the reins of prudence loose,](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=trpUW7ztMtPWsAGhxKPoCQ&q=%22if+think+you+that%22&oq=%22if+think+you+that%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...9348.10525.0.10900.4.4.0.0.0.0.131.466.0j4.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.nb-2v_89Abo)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Don’t you imagine that most people today, if confronted with a sentence like *“Give he notice and we shall let the room anew”*, would misread it?

Comment: @tchrist: Absolutely! But the OP here is a long-established SE user, so either is or should be aware that there's a sub-site specifically for learners. I will defend to the death my assertion that the syntax of example #1 above was once acceptable to at least *some* people who would describe themselves as competent in the use of English. And it's *that* kind of thing that I consider On Topic here on ELU - the question of whether or not OP should use it *today* is really a matter for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), where minor historical points are irrelevant.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I may have misread the question, at least in part. If this is about only conditionals, then I don't think you can invert all three flavors of *if Jack runs, if Jack ran, if Jack had run* and still get something that people will understand.

Comment: @tchrist: I've no idea if it's about "conditionals" or not. Would you say ***You wash and I'll dry*** is a conditional usage? I'm not sure that one's cut-and-dried. And although I think it's unlikely anyone has ever actually said *Wash you, and dry will I* (Yoda excepted! :) I wouldn't like to stake my life on the assertion that such a construction has never been "acceptable" to any native Anglophone ever.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That depends what you mean by conditional. The first part is an imperative, like saying "Stop shouting and I'll tell you", which is like "I'll tell you if you stop shouting" but pushier.

Comment: @tchrist: Ah, right. "Imperative" is the term that didn't come to me earlier. Yes - I suppose that's the clearest way of identifying the two possible intended senses of OP's first example. Imperative: *(If?) you come to the designated pickup location, then / and I'll **get / fetch** you in my car*. Conditional: *(If) you do that, I'll **get / beat the shit out of** you!*

Answer (score 2):

You don’t say:

- Come *you there, I’ll get you.

Because the *you* is wrong.

For that matter, so is *there* since the locative deictic that pairs with *come* is *here* not *there*; *there* pairs with *go*.

You instead say:

- Come here and I’ll get you.
- Go there and I’ll get you.

Which means:

- I’ll get you if you come here.
- I’ll get you if you go there.